# Laravel 4 Blade: Selecting a Column through a Model Relationship

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have three Models,

User, Token and Score. Every Score belongsTo Token and Token hasMany Score. On the other hand a User hasMany Token and Token belongsTo User.

Now I want to access the scores of a user, through the token model.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
 $scores = Token::where('user_id', $user->id)->with('scores')->get();
```

But this doesn't allow me to list all values of a column of the scores table, through:

```
 $scores->lists('colummn1');
```

Practically I want to show all scores, that belong to a user and work with the values, that are given to me.

Here is my code to this:

http://help.laravel.io/4e923306a985f72a6c965c40c6fea0ac76079dc3

Thousand thanks in advance.

G.

Comment: please show your models too

Comment: My Models are in the link above, isn't it?

Comment: I think the lists expects two parameters something like `->lists(column, key)`